# Vertical space is positioned in another location instead of I mentioned

Tags: vspace

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=0.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=1cm,right=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=Devanagari]{bengali}
\setmainlanguage{bengali}
\setotherlanguage{english}
%\newfontfamily\englishfont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Linux Biolinum O}
\newfontfamily\bengalifont[Script=Bengali]{Akaash}

\usepackage{pgffor}
\newcommand{\ListItem}[1]{\underline{\makebox[6cm][l]{#1}}}
\newcommand{\minicontent}{\foreach \x in {প্লেট,সসপেন(ঢাকনাসহ) \hfill সেট,বাটি/বোল,ভাত বাড়ার ছোট প্লেট,বন প্লেট,লবণ দানী,গ্লাস,হামান দিস্তা,চাকু,আলু ছেলার কাটার,মাজনী,ভিম,ক্লিপ,বালতি,জগ,মগ,দস্তরখানা,চামচ,বটি,ঘুটনি,লুস্নি,দড়ি(রং সহ),বাজারের ব্যাগ,চুলা,সিলিন্ডার}{\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\multido{}{3}{\begin{minipage}{0.33333333333333333333333\textwidth}
জিম্মাদারঃ \\
সাথীসংখ্যাঃ\\
\vspace{1cm}
\minicontent
\begin{itemize}[itemsep=0.0pt,leftmargin=*]
\item সামানার হেফাজত ঈমানের হেফাজত
\item সামানা গুছিয়ে রাখাও দাওয়াত
\item ইস্তেমায়ী সামানার হেফাজতে ইস্তেমায়ীয়াত  রক্ষা হয়
\item জামাত থেকে এসে তালিকা জমা দিয়ে দিলে ভাল হয়
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
}
\end{document}
```

I want to put the `vspace` after second line(সাথীসংখ্যা)।

Comment: Use `সাথীসংখ্যাঃ\\[1cm]` instead.

Comment: @egreg it works. But what is the logic behind this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `\vspace{<length>}` is used *in* a paragraph, the vertical space is added *after* the line it happens to fall in. In that context, `\\` doesn't end a paragraph.

Use

```
জিম্মাদারঃ \\
সাথীসংখ্যাঃ\\[1cm]
\minicontent
```

instead.